# I go up, I go down. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I go up, I go down. 
> 15,000, I can be. 
> Under 20 I mostly am.

Hint:

> under the crust, bubbling and broiling. I give light to places sun cannot reach.

What am I?

Comment: This seems more like a definition than a riddle

Comment: I guess. But it is more of the definition of an unknown object, hence, kind of a riddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer:

> lava lamp

Explanation:

> In a lava lamp the wax goes up and down.
>  The [highest price a lava lamp sold is $15,000](https://www.bing.com/search?q=most%20expensive%20lava%20lamp&form=APMCS1&PC=APMC)
>  The [average lava lamp is under 20 dollars](https://www.bing.com/aclk?ld=e8LAiDmh8FZJzKJ_Zo_5jATzVUCUxiO2F9ris1BwYOXssNUglnn1Lt_ZlKNIedD6-shAQQuLhinebcb-6yiGK7A37xD_Di8gKUJ014e_3BDbGfYAbSQEjqhJDw4tGCpiciph0LJoOeCRkC6-Se-i8xfBJnMyBALMz5UejCVAFEu6-pPonS&u=aHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZ3d3cuYW1hem9uLmNvbSUyZlNjaHlsbGluZy0yNzAwLTE0LTUtSW5jaC1CbGFjay1HcmFmZml0aSUyZmRwJTJmQjA3Mk0zRzVHWiUyZnJlZiUzZGFzY19kZl9CMDcyTTNHNUdaJTNmdGFnJTNkYmluZ3Nob3BwaW5nYS0yMCUyNmxpbmtDb2RlJTNkZGYwJTI2aHZhZGlkJTNkODA4MTQxNTY3NDk0NDUlMjZodm5ldHclM2RvJTI2aHZxbXQlM2RlJTI2aHZibXQlM2RiZSUyNmh2ZGV2JTNkYyUyNmh2bG9jaW50JTNkJTI2aHZsb2NwaHklM2QlMjZodnRhcmdpZCUzZHBsYS00NTg0NDEzNzM1NDc1MjUwJTI2cHNjJTNkMQ&rlid=7c076599d5b118e4c75907941ec10701)
>  Lava is under the crust, and bubbling and broiling.
>  A lamp gives light to places sun cannot reach.

Final Explanation:

> So Lava + Lamp = Lava Lamp

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Temperature

I go up, I go down

> Temperatures go up and down

15 000 I can be, under 20 I mostly am

> 15 000 degrees is possible, but we humans are on average living under 20 degrees

Under the crust, bubbling and broiling

> Temperatures makes things like lava bubble under the Earth's crust

I give light to places the sun cannot reach

> When something becomes hot enough, it shines with a bright glow

Comment: Great logic, but that’s not it. Clue: it is a man made object and it is two different words. The two sentences in the clue about the name represent the two different words.

Comment: [*"15 000 I can be"* is not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lava#Temperature). Not on Earth, not even [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_of_Earth#Core)

Answer (score -4):

> Magma

The puzzle says under the crust it's bubbling and broiling.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Feel free to take our [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). Your answer is a bit low quality, and it doesn't support all parts of the puzzle. Furthermore, this riddle has already been answered, feel free to check the other answers to that riddle to see what would be a good quality answer.